# HttpHeaders instantiate with constructor vs using Set

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I noticed a really strange behavior of HttpHeaders not applying correctly if instantiating the custom headers in a constructor.

```
public signIn(otpAuth): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders ({
        'X-OTP': otpAuth
    });
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: httpHeaders});
}
```

This will not work, the headers are not visible in a network request. **<s>One thing I noticed is if I hardcode the `otpAuth` it will work as expected.</s> (if hardcoded as string)**

The second approach is using `HttpHeaders().set()` and works without flaws.

```
public signIn(otpAuth): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('X-OTP', otpAuth);
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});
}
```

`otpAuth` is always defined. Even if I log it, it is there, so why does the first approach seem to ignore it?

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5w1fgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy.service.ts)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like **otpAuth** being a number causes a problem. If it is converted to a string the constructor approach works.

```
  const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders ({
        'X-OTP': '' + otpAuth
    });
```